# How to obtain value of input tag in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, tags

I want to that coming from input and URL for doing a request to API server but I can not get input value that's why, result always null or undefined btw I checked manually other parts works. I reviewed pretty similar code but mostly I am missing fundamental of DOM principle

sample input for evaluate whether working '23205542924'

thanks for everything.

JS

```
const input = document.getElementById("in");
console.log(input.value+" gel");
const btn = document.getElementById("button");
const URL = "https://openapi.izmir.bel.tr/api/iztek/bakiyesorgulama/" + input;
console.log(URL);

async function fetchValue() {
  const response = await fetch(URL);
  return await response.json();
}

const amount = () => {
  fetchValue().then((response) => {
    const result = response["UlasimKartBakiyesi"];
    const message = "Value is:" + result["MevcutBakiye"];
    document.getElementsByClassName("yazdir")[0].innerHTML = message;
  });
};

btn.addEventListener("click", amount);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <p class="yazdir"></p>
    <label for="">card input:</label>
    <input name="in" type="text" maxlength="512" id="in" class="in"/>
    <button id="button">click me </button>
    <script src="./new.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should read the value of the input when it is needed (on the button click here), not when the page is loaded and nothing has been entered.

```js
async function fetchValue() {
  const response = await fetch("https://openapi.izmir.bel.tr/api/iztek/bakiyesorgulama/" + input.value);
  return await response.json();
}
```

Comment: appriciate it  works !!!

Comment: There are many, many, many duplicates of this question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey right but I confused am not dominated in this subject so I've just realized